# InApp Purchases. No auth plugin to verify credentials for accounts of type com.apple.account.iTunesStore.sandbox

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, tvos, storekit

I'm using `.storekit` configuration. When trying to make a purchase for such a product there is an error

> <SKPaymentQueue: 0x600001240ce0>: Payment completed with error: Error
> Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=500 "Unhandled exception"
> UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600001c62160 {Error
> Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=100 "Authentication Failed"
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The verify credentials call
> failed., NSLocalizedDescription=Authentication Failed,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x600001c60960 {Error Domain=com.apple.accounts
> Code=4 "No auth plugin to verify credentials for accounts of type
> com.apple.account.iTunesStore.sandbox"
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No auth plugin to verify credentials
> for accounts of type com.apple.account.iTunesStore.sandbox}}}},
> NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred,
> NSLocalizedDescription=Unhandled exception}

How to fix that?

Answer (score 9):

**Update**

For someone who want test IAP on simulator:

You can follow the link to add configuration and then IAP will working on simulator perfectly.

https://github.com/russell-archer/StoreHelper/blob/main/Documentation/guide.md#get-started

**Old answer**

I guess you test IAP in the simulator. Test it in real devices is worked for me.

Comment: When you are testing on real device have you used sandbox tester account or a real one ?

Comment: @Sudarshan I used sandbox tester on real device. You can check the account in `setting - apple store - sandbox account`.

Comment: OK and are building this app with React Native or any other technology ? Because, I am facing this issue with React Native and my app is freezing once I got the "You are All Set" popup after performing IAP using revenue cat

Comment: @Sudarshan I use SwiftUI + StoreHelper to build

Answer (score -2):

For me by resetting all settings of my iPhone devices it worked.